# Target of <a href="xyz.php"> to a specific div on the php page without redirecting the php page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a php page which comes by clicking on `<a href="xyz.php">` from left side menu on a  specific div named `id="portfolio"` on same page. I've searched alot but didn't get people working, as some says convert your page to html and separate the php code to a separate file. but the problem is I've whole project and so many php pages so this method will take time. Is there any way to do this using `target` html method in `<a href="" target="portfolio">` so when user click of a it will target the url to portfolio div or something like this or I've to use Jquery for this purpose ???

My code is:

```
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/dist/scripts.min.js"></script>

 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



 <div class="main">
 <div class="nav-side-menu">
 <div class="brand">Brand Logo</div>


    <div class="menu-list">

        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
              </a>
            </li>

            <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> UI Elements <span class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz.php">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz.php">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz.php">Typography</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz.php">FontAwesome</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz.php">Slider</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz.php">Panels</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz.php">Widgets</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz.php">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
            </ul>



        </ul>
 </div>

 </div>

 <div class="portfolio"><h1>My Page</h1></div>
 </div>
```

Style.css

```
.nav-side-menu {
 overflow: auto;
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 200;
 background-color: #2e353d;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 color: #e1ffff;
 }
.portfolio {
 background-color:#F3F3F3 ;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 300px;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 display:inline-block;
 -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
  } 
  .collapse-expand {
   background-color: #d9d9d9;
   border-top-color: #d9d9d9;
   -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
   transition: left 0.5s ease;
   }
  .collapse-expand {
   position: fixed;
   height: 35px;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 300px;
   border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
   border-top: 1px solid #bbbabb;
   background-color: #d9d9d9;
   cursor: pointer;
   -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
   transition: left 0.5s ease;
   }
  .fa-angle-left
   {
  padding-left: 95px;
padding-top: 5px;
/*-moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
transition: left 0.5s ease;*/
}

.nav-side-menu .brand {
 background-color: #23282e;
 line-height: 50px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 }

 .nav-side-menu ul,
 .nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
 line-height: 35px;
 cursor: pointer;

  }
 .nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
 .nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0da";
  display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
   vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
   }
  .nav-side-menu ul .active,
  .nav-side-menu li .active {
   border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69; 
   }
 .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
 .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
   }

 body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Here is my **[Js Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ta0a5821/)** working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iFrame` or JQuery's `.load()` method

`iFrame` : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

`.load()` : http://api.jquery.com/load/

**Edited**

Handle click

```js
$('a[data-async-load]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var externalUrl = $(this).attr('data-async-load');
  alert(externalUrl); // Replace the with .load() method
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="sample3.php">Do't load async</a>
<a data-async-load="sample1.php" href>Load Async 1</a>
<a data-async-load="sample2.php" href>Load Async 2</a>
```

Comment: ok if use iFrame than it will be inside div ? ?? does it change my style of div ??

Comment: load can be used to get the content of a url and render it on target element

Comment: can you give me the example ??

Comment: it's at the bottom on the link i mentioned in answer. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: ok i got it but in my case I want to run this when user clicks an option from sub menu than how to perform this on {<a onclick="somefun(this.value);"  value="abc.php"></a>} tag ???? and somefun(abc) contain that load function ?

Comment: ok in this {$('a[data-async-load]').click(function(e)  } where you have use alert we can use that load query ?? ? and pass that alert variable and than show that page in div ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159449/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-and-naveed-cheema).

Comment: Great! So you followed this approach?

Comment: hahahaah yeah till the end. Thanks to you for understanding my describing that what I want (:

Answer (score 0):

It is Done by using `.load()` having described in this [Link](http://api.jquery.com/load/) Here is my working **[JS Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ta0a5821/5/)**